# Why this problem happend in my react function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to get information from redux but this error happen and i dont know how could i fix it. That's my first time with react and react Hooks, sorry but i'm lost.
Thank you in advance.

1. `React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "header" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

**My code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Notifications from '../Notifications';

import logo from '~/assets/headerLogo.svg';
import { Container, Profile, Content } from './styles';

export default function header() {
  const profile = useSelector(state => state.user.profile);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <nav>
          <img src={logo} alt="GoBarber" />
          <Link to="/dashboard">DASHBOARD</Link>
        </nav>
        <aside>
          <Notifications />
          <Profile>
            <div>
              <strong>{profile.name}</strong>
              <Link to="/profile">Meu Perfil</Link>
            </div>
            <img
              src={
                profile.avatar.url ||
                'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/50/abott@adorable.png'
              }
              alt="profile"
            />
          </Profile>
        </aside>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rules of hooks lint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) depends on naming conventions to tell what is a component, what is a hook, and what is any other function. Functions beginning with `use` (eg, `useEffect`, `useMyCustomStuff`) are assumed to be hooks. Functions beginning with a capital letter are assumed to be components. Your code does neither, so it assumes this is just a normal function unrelated to hooks or components.

Rename `header` to `Header` to fix this.